# Same ip, different route?

Tags: networking, ping, comparison, traceroute

There's a set of ip addresses that are hosted from the same ISP servers, but when i pick a random ip address from that set, it picks the right route or maybe the wrong one. I'll give you an example: 
ISP ip addresses: 94.0/38.xx.xx

If i do a Tracert to a random number like (94.2.55.112) it goes like this:

```
1- 84.111.xx.xx (ISP 1)
2- 84.111.xx.xx
3- 84.110.xx.xx 
4- 195.27.xx.xx (ISP 2)
5- 195.28.xx.xx
6- 99.34.xx.xx (ISP 3)
7- 94.2.55.112 (ISP 3)
```

However, if i do a tracert to that six route (99.34.xx.xx) it changes completely, and goes between so many ISPs before getting there.

Q: Why did the routing table change? Why wouldn't it follows the same route as mentioned above? That's so frustrating, this can't be true. I never knew that networking route would be so complicated like that.

Comment: Who says the routing table changed? ISP 1 may know a good route to IPS2 and dump packets for unknown destinations to ISP3.  Maybe for no good reason. Maybe to balance a load.  More importantly, why do you care? As long as it is outside your network and you get a good connection this should not influence you at all.

Comment: It seems you have only given us what you think the problem might be, rather than what you are trying to resolve overall. Is this actually causing a problem? Or are you just frustrated because it is not taking the route you would like?

Comment: @CharlieRB Yes. And as a result, the packets goes back and forth between overseas which increase the ping/latency from 30-50ms(good route) to 240-250ms(bad route) and neither you, me or anyone would agree to this confusing behavior right? That's why it DOES NOT MAKE A SENSE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It needs a couple of explanations:

First of all, how traceroute works:

1. Traceroute sends a package to the destination IP (94.2.55.112) with **TLL=1**
2. The receving router decrements TTL and because **TTL=0** discards the package and returns a `TTL exceeded`
3. Traceroute sends a package to the destination IP (94.2.55.112) with **TLL=2**
4. The receving router decrements TTL and pass it to the next hop.
5. The next hop decrements TTL and because **TTL=0** discards the package and returns a `TTL exceeded`
6. Traceroute sends a package to the destination IP (94.2.55.112) with **TLL=3**

.
.
.

And so on, until the package reach its destination (94.2.55.112).

---

Now, let's check how routers work:

When a router receives a packet, its **only** mission is to send it to the next hop as soon as possible.

To achieve this mission, the router makes a **decision** based on a routing table; the routing table for an internet table could be huge. Checking the table and making a decision is called **process switching** and is the slowest way to do it. So there are some tricks to speed it up.

- There is **fast switching**. With it, after a packet has been sent to the next hop, the routing information about how to get to the destination is stored in a *fast cache*.  When the router receives another packet that is directed to the same destination it uses the cache. It's faster than the traditional way.
- Cisco has developed a technique called **Cisco Express Forwarding  or CEF**, that is even faster.  CEF is a propietary system that stores information in a way that can be queried very quickly.

---

Now let's get all together:

When the destination of a *traceroute* is a **host** (94.2.55.112, for example), on the first packet the routers will use the traditional way (*process switching*) to know where is the destination, but after that in the next packets the routers will use *fast switching* or *CEF*. From origin to destination there will be a *fixed path*.

When the destination of a *traceroute* is a **router** (99.34.xx.xx), the intermediate routers will do the same as before (first packet with *process switching* and from then cache), but the destination router won't do it because there are no next hop. So, the destination router will do *process switching* to respond to each received packet.

The big problem arises when the destination router has two or more connections to different ISPs and the connections are doing **load balancing**.

Load balancing means that to avoid that a single connection gets overloaded until the router uses the next one, it uses a mechanism as *round-robin* to evenly distribute the traffic among all its connections.

Now you have the explosive mix for your situation: A traceroute to a router, it will use *process switching* for every package, that is influenced by load balancing and you have **every time a different path**.

Sorry for the long explanation, but as the result is a sum of multiple mechanisms, I wanted to make them as clear as possible.

Comment: Except a router is a host too and doesn’t have to do decide anything when it’s the destination. ;)

Answer (score 0):

The routing table didn’t change, but the destination did. And that’s what’s looked at when trying to find the next hop.

Some routing table along the way had a different next hop for destinations 94.2.55.112 and 99.34.xx.xx. Not strange at all, considering they’re in different /8 subnets. While it may seem that way, routes are not necessarily defined with the physical location/proximity in mind.

Comment: Well the destination didn't change. But the routing to the (Same) destination changes Only on some random numbers. It's like saying: instead of going from south to north to get to the station, we can take another subway road from south, east, middle, west to north. :/

Comment: Of course it did. First, you ran `tracert 94.2.55.112`, next you ran `tracert 99.34.xx.xx`. It really can’t get any more obvious.